# How do I reorder (pop and push) items from WP_Query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, order

I have this piece of code:

```
$normal_args  = array(
    'order'               => 'desc',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_query'          => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'rw_show_at_position',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'post__not_in'        => $prev_post_ids,
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'      => get_option( 'column_right' ),
    'post_type'           => array(
        'opinion',
        'especiales',
        'clasificados',
        'portadadeldia',
        'anunciantes',
        'post',
        'pages',
        'esp-publicitarios'
    )
);

$normal_query = new WP_Query( $normal_args );

$i = 0;
if ( $normal_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $normal_query->have_posts() ) {
        $normal_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        echo $i . ' ==> ';
        ?>

        <?php
        if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'esp-publicitarios' ) {
            $adv_pos = rwmb_meta( 'rw_adversiting_position', 'type=select', $post->ID );
            echo $adv_pos . EOL;
        } else {
        ?>
            // do something here
        <?php
        }
        $i ++;
    }
}
```

And I want to reorder items based on `post_type` and a metakey `rw_adversiting_position` and then display them normally. Right now I am getting this result:

```
0 ==> 183034 ==> 9
1 ==> 183033 ==> 6
2 ==> 183032 ==> 3
3 ==> 183002 ==>
4 ==> 182973 ==>
5 ==> 182971 ==>
6 ==> 182969 ==>
7 ==> 182999 ==>
8 ==> 182997 ==>
9 ==> 182995 ==>
10 ==> 182962 ==>
11 ==> 182948 ==>
```

That's because only the 0, 1 and 2 are `esp-publicitarios` post types. The number at the right 9, 6 and 3 is the position where I should push the item so having this info the result should be something like:

```
0 ==> 183002 ==>
1 ==> 182973 ==>
2 ==> 182971 ==>
2 ==> 183032 ==> 3
4 ==> 182969 ==>
5 ==> 182999 ==>
6 ==> 183033 ==> 6
7 ==> 182997 ==>
8 ==> 182995 ==>
9 ==> 183034 ==> 9
10 ==> 182962 ==>
11 ==> 182948 ==>
```

Can any give me some ideas to achieve this?

**UPDATE 1**

I did found [this](http://kuttler.eu/code/order-posts-in-a-wp_query-manually/) but I am not sure how to apply it.

**UPDATE 2**

This is the PHP code for achieve the sorting, `sort_position` could be `rw_adversiting_position`:

```
$arr           = [
    '183034' => [ 'sort_position' => 9 ],
    '183033' => [ 'sort_position' => 5 ],
    '183032' => [ 'sort_position' => 3 ],
    '183002' => [ ],
    '182973' => [ ],
    '182971' => [ ],
    '182969' => [ ],
    '182999' => [ ],
    '182997' => [ ],
    '182995' => [ ],
    '182962' => [ ],
    '182948' => [ ]
];

$count         = count( $arr );
$has_sortorder = [ ];
$no_sortorder  = [ ];
krsort( $arr );
foreach ( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    if ( isset( $val['sort_position'] ) ) {
        $has_sortorder[ $val['sort_position'] ] = [ $key, $val ];
    } else {
        $no_sortorder[] = [ $key, $val ];
    }
}


$out = [ ];
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++ ) {
    if ( isset( $has_sortorder[ $i ] ) ) {
        $out[ $has_sortorder[ $i ][0] ] = $has_sortorder[ $i ][1];
    } else {
        $element            = array_shift( $no_sortorder );
        $out[ $element[0] ] = $element[1];
    }
}

var_dump( $out );
```

I just need to know how to apply this to WP_Query before get the result, any?

**UPDATE 3**

Here is a snippet of `var_export($normal_query->posts)` as you can see there is no meta-key so I can order based on values of a meta, then how?

```
$var = array(
    0 => WP_Post::__set_state( array(
        'ID'                    => 183034,
        'post_author'           => '4',
        'post_date'             => '2015-12-01 16:44:35',
        'post_date_gmt'         => '2015-12-01 21:14:35',
        'post_content'          => '',
        'post_title'            => 'Espacio Pub 3',
        'post_excerpt'          => '',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'comment_status'        => 'closed',
        'ping_status'           => 'closed',
        'post_password'         => '',
        'post_name'             => 'espacio-pub-3',
        'to_ping'               => '',
        'pinged'                => '',
        'post_modified'         => '2015-12-01 16:54:38',
        'post_modified_gmt'     => '2015-12-01 21:24:38',
        'post_content_filtered' => '',
        'post_parent'           => 0,
        'guid'                  => 'http://elclarinweb.local/?post_type=esp-publicitarios&p=183034',
        'menu_order'            => 0,
        'post_type'             => 'esp-publicitarios',
        'post_mime_type'        => '',
        'comment_count'         => '0',
        'filter'                => 'raw',
    ) ),
    1 => WP_Post::__set_state( array(
        'ID'                    => 183033,
        'post_author'           => '4',
        'post_date'             => '2015-12-01 16:44:13',
        'post_date_gmt'         => '2015-12-01 21:14:13',
        'post_content'          => '',
        'post_title'            => 'Espacio Pub 2',
        'post_excerpt'          => '',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'comment_status'        => 'closed',
        'ping_status'           => 'closed',
        'post_password'         => '',
        'post_name'             => '183033',
        'to_ping'               => '',
        'pinged'                => '',
        'post_modified'         => '2015-12-01 16:44:21',
        'post_modified_gmt'     => '2015-12-01 21:14:21',
        'post_content_filtered' => '',
        'post_parent'           => 0,
        'guid'                  => 'http://elclarinweb.local/?post_type=esp-publicitarios&p=183033',
        'menu_order'            => 0,
        'post_type'             => 'esp-publicitarios',
        'post_mime_type'        => '',
        'comment_count'         => '0',
        'filter'                => 'raw',
    ) ),
    2 => WP_Post::__set_state( array(
        'ID'                    => 183032,
        'post_author'           => '4',
        'post_date'             => '2015-12-01 15:53:56',
        'post_date_gmt'         => '2015-12-01 20:23:56',
        'post_content'          => '',
        'post_title'            => 'Publicidad 1',
        'post_excerpt'          => '',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'comment_status'        => 'closed',
        'ping_status'           => 'closed',
        'post_password'         => '',
        'post_name'             => 'publicidad-1',
        'to_ping'               => '',
        'pinged'                => '',
        'post_modified'         => '2015-12-01 15:53:56',
        'post_modified_gmt'     => '2015-12-01 20:23:56',
        'post_content_filtered' => '',
        'post_parent'           => 0,
        'guid'                  => 'http://elclarinweb.local/?post_type=esp-publicitarios&p=183032',
        'menu_order'            => 0,
        'post_type'             => 'esp-publicitarios',
        'post_mime_type'        => '',
        'comment_count'         => '0',
        'filter'                => 'raw',
    ) ),
    3 => WP_Post::__set_state( array(
            'ID'                    => 183002,
            'post_author'           => '7',
            'post_date'             => '2015-11-22 00:08:00',
            'post_date_gmt'         => '2015-11-22 04:38:00',
            'post_content'          => 'Borrón y cuenta nueva es lo que han hecho los Bravos de Margarita en este comienzo de la segunda parte de la campaña, en la que ayer sumaron su cuarto triunfo seguido, al vencer a los Tiburones de La Guaira 5 carreras por 3. Margarita, que ganó dos de tres ante los escualos en la semana, madrugó al dominicano Alexis Candelario, quien llegó a dicha cita como el mejor lanzador del campeonato. Los artilleros isleños fabricaron cuatro de sus cinco carreras en las primeras dos entradas, catapultados por un doble impulsor de dos de Eliézer Alfonzo. “No importa quién esté en la lomita contraria, siempre que los muchachos crean en ellos mismos, estos van a ser los resultados”, señaló el dirigente Henry Blanco. Bravos se haría presente en el marcador una vez más en el sexto con doble remolcador del jardinero Junior Sosa y aguantaría un intento de remontada de los litoralenses en la parte final para sellar el lauro. “La mentalidad que tenemos es no pensar en la primera parte, hay que salir a ganar”, indicó Alfonzo, quien cerró el cotejo de 5-2 con un par de impulsadas y ahora acumula cinco rayitas traídas al plato en los últimos dos desafíos. “Estaba bastante perdido cuando comenzó la temporada, pero he hecho el ajuste necesario”.',
            'post_title'            => 'Ahora Bravos es puntero de la LVBP',
            'post_excerpt'          => 'Las curiosidades del nuevo sistema de puntos del torneo coloca al antiguo colero de puntero',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'comment_status'        => 'open',
            'ping_status'           => 'open',
            'post_password'         => '',
            'post_name'             => 'ahora-bravos-es-puntero-de-la-lvbp',
            'to_ping'               => '',
            'pinged'                => '',
            'post_modified'         => '2015-11-22 00:08:00',
            'post_modified_gmt'     => '2015-11-22 04:38:00',
            'post_content_filtered' => '',
            'post_parent'           => 0,
            'guid'                  => 'http://elclarinweb.local/?p=183002',
            'menu_order'            => 0,
            'post_type'             => 'post',
            'post_mime_type'        => '',
            'comment_count'         => '0',
            'filter'                => 'raw'
        )
    )
);
```

**UPDATE 4**

@bosco I have made some minors changes to your code and now it looks as follow:

```
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( &$posts, $return = false ) {
    $ad_posts = array();

    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $position      = intval( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true ) );
        $post_date     = $post->post_date;
        $post_modified = $post->post_modified;

        if ( ! empty( $position ) ) {
            if ( ! empty ( $ad_posts ) ) {
                if ( $post_date > $ad_posts[ $position ]->post_date || $post_modified > $ad_posts[ $position ]->post_modified ) {
                    $ad_posts[ $position ] = $post;
                }
            } else {
                $ad_posts[ $position ] = $post;
            }
        } else {
            $content_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort( $ad_posts );

    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach ( $ad_posts as $position => $ad ) {
        array_splice( $content_posts, $position, 0, array( $ad ) );
    }

    // If $return is true, return the resulting array. Otherwise replace the original $posts array with it.
    if ( $return ) {
        return $content_posts;
    } else {
        $posts = $content_posts;
    }
}
```

If I debug this on the template I get the following output:

```
echo '<pre> BEFORE';
echo count($normal_query->posts);
echo '</pre>';

wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( $normal_query->posts );

echo '<pre> AFTER';
echo count($normal_query->posts);
echo '</pre>';

// Output
BEFORE25
AFTER23
```

The AFTER is the right value but the loop is using the BEFORE and is adding to empty elements on the loop, why? See [this pic](http://content.screencast.com/users/ReynierPM/folders/Snagit/media/52f01187-79a5-4363-a8d1-e8c1decd5490/12.04.2015-22.01.png) for more info.

Comment: The posts are stored in the query object, `$normal_query->posts`, you can reorder them there before running the loop.

Comment: @Milo yes, you're almost right, but `$normal_query->posts` is missing meta-key so I don't know the value of `rw_adversiting_position` which is the key holding the position for reorder the items. Can you give me some help?

Comment: Wait... so you're not actually trying to order them by `post_type`, just `rw_adversiting_position`, right?

Comment: @bosco right, what matter to me rather than `post_type` is the value of met `rw_adversiting_position`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Metadata API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) to retrieve the `rw_advertising_position` metadata for each post, seperate the ads from the content, and then re-insert the ads at the proper locations:

```
/**
 * Extracts from an array posts with positional metadata and re-inserts them at the proper
 * indices. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210493
 **/
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( &$posts, $return = false ) {
    $ad_posts      = array();
    $content_posts = array();

    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data    
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $position = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true );

        if( ! empty( $position ) )
            $ad_posts[ intval( $position ) ] = $post;
        else
            $content_posts[] = $post;  
    }

    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort( $ad_posts );

    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach( $ad_posts as $position => $ad ) {
        array_splice( $content_posts, $position, 0, array( $ad ) );
    }

    // If $return is true, return the resulting array. Otherwise replace the original $posts array with it.
    if( $return )
        return $content_posts;
    else
        $posts = $content_posts;
}
```

> #### DISCLAIMER
>
> In the example above, I specify a function parameter `&$posts` which instructs PHP to use a [*pass-by-reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) evaluation strategy for the argument passed to the function as `$posts`. This means that instead of referring to a locally-scoped copy of the data passed as the first argument, the `$posts` variable will refer to the data *at it's original place in memory*.
>
> Here I've used this mechanism to provide the (default) option to directly re-arrange an array of post objects without needing to handle a return value. The function itself merely sorting an array, I choose to pass the array argument by reference in order to provide behavior more consistent with [all 12 of PHP's array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).
>
> As [@Andrei Gheorghiu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/45169/andrei-gheorghiu) points out in the comments, passing by reference can produce unexpected results if you're unfamiliar with the practice. In such a scenario you may wish to steer clear of it which can be done by setting the `$return` argument in the example to `true`, or to be completely safe [remove the option entirely as Andrei has](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210493#answer-210876).

In your template:

```
// [...]
$normal_query = new WP_Query( $normal_args );

wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( $normal_query->posts );

if ( $normal_query->have_posts() ) {
// [...]
```

I haven't tested that code - it's just for illustrative purposes.

Alternately, using a second query to retrieve the ads alone might work a little better.

Comment: I think I will need to change a few things since posts with `rw_adversiting_position` meta are going to the end of the list and that's wrong but that's not the problem I need to fix right now. I have tested your code and it works it just doesn't display `the_title()` or any other values for post with meta `rw_adversiting_position` see [this pic](http://content.screencast.com/users/ReynierPM/folders/Snagit/media/60e9a5b6-8929-47c1-a6c2-84a74d762794/12.03.2015-00.01.png) what's wrong? I need to fix this before fix the sorting, any help or advise?

Comment: There were some oversights in my example. It should probably work now. If not, `var_dump( $normal_query->posts );` after calling the `wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( $normal_query->posts );` to figure out what's gone wrong. You can write your own sorting function as well - the important part is that you can use the Metadata API to retrieve posts' `rw_advertising_position` meta-values.

Comment: it's working now, thanks and yes I got what code does, good answer

Comment: can you help me with **UPDATE 4**? I have not idea why the loop is using the before `$normal_query->post` instead the modified by the function one, any advise?

Comment: @ReynierPM I'm guessing here, but I think you want `if( isset( $ad_posts[ $position ] ) )` instead of `if( ! empty( $ad_posts ) )`. I just noticed another oversight in my code, as well - `$content_posts` should have been declared as an empty array right beside `$ad_posts`... it's probably not causing the error that you're experiencing - just a good practice.

Comment: Bosco, while your solution successfully modifies the `posts` property of the WP_Query, passing it by referrence is bad practice, specifically because you are only modifying the `posts` property of the query. If, for example, someone would run a normal WP loop on that query (`while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()` the `have_posts()` would still hold the initial count of posts of the query, not the filtered count. You should probably return the filtered posts in a variable so it could be used in a `foreach`. Please revise.

Comment: I just want to make my position clearer: **I think your answer is good** and provides a fully **working solution** for the issue at hand. But it should return the filtered posts, not directly modify the query property.

Comment: @Andrei as it's written, I don't see how my example could possibly alter the number of posts in the array - there is a 1 to 1 relationship between the number of items input and the number that come out.

Comment: You're right, bosco. It's just reordering, not filtering. My bad for not looking first. Obviously, he modified it for filtering. More of a reason not to pass query params by referrence on WPSE answers & examples. The risk of missuse is higher.

Comment: @Andrei you make a good point. But I'm of the mindset that people shouldn't be copying + pasting code they don't understand; I don't feel it's the community's responsibility to protect people from themselves, but rather guide them along the right path by example and provide opportunities to learn. As such, I won't alter my example code as I believe passing by reference is entirely appropriate in the case of sorting an array - but I did add a disclaimer to elaborate upon it and add a warning.

Answer (score 2):

This is a revised version of [bosco's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/210613/45169) answer which **does answer the question** but adds too much flexibility by allowing direct modification of query properties, that I personally consider bad practice.

```
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( $posts ) {
    $ad_posts      = array();
    $content_posts = array();

    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data    
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $position = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true );

        if( ! empty( $position ) )
            $ad_posts[ intval( $position ) ] = $post;
        else
            $content_posts[] = $post;  
    }

    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort( $ad_posts );

    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach( $ad_posts as $position => $ad ) {
        array_splice( $content_posts, $position, 0, array( $ad ) );
    }

    return $content_posts;
}
```

After running the filter, we check to see if any posts were returned and if so, we use them in a `foreach` that outputs our result:

```
$normal_query = new WP_Query( $normal_args );

$filtered_posts = wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position( $normal_query->posts );

if ( count($filtered_posts) ) :
    foreach ($filtered_posts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        /* run any functions available in WP loop here 
         * (the_title(), the_content(), etc...)
         *
         */
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: I must said that your mod works perfectly and fix the issue I was having with extra items at end of original array, I will keep @bosco answer as accepted but I upvote yours. If the dupe is removed from the other question feel free to post the same answer there and I will accept the question