# How to keep a CPT stick to specific position?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, customization

I have created a CPT (`esp-publicitarios`) using [Metabox](http://metabox.io) plugin with the following code:

```
add_filter('rwmb_meta_boxes', 'elclarin_register_meta_boxes');

function elclarin_register_meta_boxes($meta_boxes)
{
    // Better has an underscore as last sign
    $prefix = 'rw_';

    // meta box - advertising related news
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'advertising_related_news',
        'title' => __('Crear espacio publicitario'),
        'post_types' => array('esp-publicitarios'),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => __('Choose related news'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}advertising_related_link",
                'type' => 'select_advanced',
                'options' => $options,
                'clone' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'name' => __('Choose an image'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}adversiting_image",
                'type' => 'image_advanced',
                'force_delete' => true,
                'max_file_uploads' => 1,
            ),
            array(
                'name' => __('Choose a position'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}adversiting_position",
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => array(
                    '2' => 'Position 3',
                    '5' => 'Position 6',
                    '8' => 'Position 9',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => __('Position'),
                'id' => "{$prefix}show_at_position",
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'std' => 1,
            ),
        ),
        'validation' => array(
            'rules' => array(
                "{$prefix}advertising_related_link" => array(
                    'required' => true,
                ),
            ),
            'messages' => array(
                "{$prefix}advertising_related_link" => array(
                    'required' => __('You must choose a related news', $prefix),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
```

That works perfect. I need to insert the adversiting in a given position (3, 6 or 9 as shown above) so I have made the following function:

```
/**
 * Extracts from an array posts with positional metadata and re-inserts them at the proper
 * indices. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210493
 **/
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position(&$posts, $return = false)
{
    $ad_posts = array();
    $content_posts = array();
    $related_post = array();
    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $position = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true);
        $post_date = $post->post_date;
        $post_modified = $post->post_modified;
        if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_advertising_related_link', true) !== 0) {
            $related_post[] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_advertising_related_link', true);
        }
        if (!empty($position)) {
            if (isset($ad_posts[$position])) {
                if ($post_date > $ad_posts[$position]->post_date || $post_modified > $ad_posts[$position]->post_modified) {
                    $ad_posts[$position] = $post;
                }
            } else {
                $ad_posts[$position] = $post;
            }
        } else {
            $content_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }
    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort($ad_posts);
    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach ($ad_posts as $position => $ad) {
        array_splice($content_posts, $position, 0, array($ad));
    }
    foreach ($content_posts as $key => $post) {
        if (in_array($post->ID, $related_post)) {
            unset($content_posts[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $content_posts;
}
```

Next, this is how I use the code above in then front page:

```
$normal_args = array(
    'order' => 'desc',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rw_show_at_position',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
    'post__not_in' => $prev_post_ids,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('column_right'),
    'post_type' => array(
        'opinion',
        'especiales',
        'clasificados',
        'portadadeldia',
        'anunciantes',
        'post',
        'pages',
        'esp-publicitarios',
    ),
);
$normal_query = new WP_Query($normal_args);
$i = 0;
// Espacios publicitarios hook
$filtered_posts = wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position($normal_query->posts);
if (count($filtered_posts)) {
    foreach ($filtered_posts as $post) {
       // ....
    }
}
```

That "works" but I have a problem, because the CPT is tied to the post then it moves out any time I add a new post and I need to keep it stick to its position, in other words if I set the CPT to be on the position 3 and link a post to it then that CPT and the post should remain on the position 3 until I remove from there, can I get some help from the community? I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you index `$related_posts` by position along with `$ad_posts`, you can probably splice/insert them in at the same position... eg.

```
function wpse_210493_apply_advertising_position(&$posts, $return = false)
{
    $ad_posts = array();
    $content_posts = array();
    $related_post = array();
    // Seperate $posts into "Ads" and "Content" arrays based on whether or not they have 'rw_adversiting_position' meta-data
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $position = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_adversiting_position', true);
        $post_date = $post->post_date;
        $post_modified = $post->post_modified;

        // add an index to related_posts inside the position check
        if (!empty($position)) {
            // move this inside position check
            $related_post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rw_advertising_related_link', true);
            if (isset($ad_posts[$position])) {
                if ($post_date > $ad_posts[$position]->post_date || $post_modified > $ad_posts[$position]->post_modified) {
                    $ad_posts[$position] = $post;
                    // add position index to related post
                    if ($related_post) {$related_post[$position] = $related_post;}
                }
            } else {
                $ad_posts[$position] = $post;
                // add position index to related post
                if ($related_post) {$related_post[$position] = $related_post;}
            }
        } else {
            $content_posts[] = $post;
        }

    }

    // Sort the ads from smallest position index to greatest such that re-insertion properly factors in all ads
    ksort($ad_posts);
    // Add the ads back into the content at their specified positions
    foreach ($ad_posts as $position => $ad) {
        array_splice($content_posts, $position, 0, array($ad));
        // add the match related post in
        array_splice($content_posts, $position, 0, array($related_post[$position]));
    }

    // then there is no need for this now
    // foreach ($content_posts as $key => $post) {
    //     if (in_array($post->ID, $related_post)) {
    //        unset($content_posts[$key]);
    //    }
    // }

    return $content_posts;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the full function? I am not following you at all